# Is this long running select query running optimally?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have a long running query (~10 minutes) that is generated by an application which I cannot control. However the underlying tables that the query runs on are in my control. I am pasting the query and it's execution plan here. I don't have sufficient expertise to interpret the execution plan and identify what changes if any can be made on the underlying tables (like adding/removing indexes), to help execute this any faster.

The query itself looks like a straight forward star schema join where a large fact table is being joined against multiple dimension tables. Can someone suggest any changes that can be made to these tables, especially the main fact table with ~ 50 million rows to make these kind of queries run faster?

The record counts of the tables involved are listed below

```
/B28/EUDIQSBV   58,528,276
/B28/SUDDX6I4   7,330
/B28/SUDDHZNC   312
/B28/SUDDZMED   267
/B28/SUDDFNH0   84
/B28/SUDD8DGN   76
/B28/SUDDDY4S   75
/B28/SUDDCQ0M   46
/B28/SUDD741B   36
/B28/SUDDC4PW   23
/B28/SUDD94IW   21
/B28/DUDIQSBVD  11
/B28/SUDDXGOI   8
/B28/DUDIQSBVP  7
/B28/SUDDCD88   5
/B28/SUDD8UPI   2
/BI0/0600000051 0
```

**EDIT:**

On request, here are the list of indexes in the /B28/EUDIQSBV table.

```
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBV1
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBV2
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBV3
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBV4
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBV5
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBV6
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBV7
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBV8
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBV9
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBVA
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBVB
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBVC
Index using Dimension /CPMB/UDIQSBVD
Non-Unique Index (Key Fields) for Table /B28/EUDIQSBV
```

And the table definition itself is as follows:
[image: Table Definition]

**The query:**

```
SELECT
  "S1080"."/B28/S_UDDZMED" AS "/CPMB/UDDZMED" ,
  "S1081"."/B28/S_UDD8DGN" AS "/CPMB/UDD8DGN" ,
  "S1082"."/B28/S_UDDFNH0" AS "/CPMB/UDDFNH0" ,
  "S1083"."/B28/S_UDDX6I4" AS "/CPMB/UDDX6I4" ,
  "S1084"."/B28/S_UDDXGOI" AS "/CPMB/UDDXGOI" ,
  "S1085"."/B28/S_UDD741B" AS "/CPMB/UDD741B" ,
  "S1086"."/B28/S_UDDC4PW" AS "/CPMB/UDDC4PW" ,
  "S1087"."/B28/S_UDD8UPI" AS "/CPMB/UDD8UPI" ,
  "S1088"."/B28/S_UDD94IW" AS "/CPMB/UDD94IW" ,
  "S1089"."/B28/S_UDDCD88" AS "/CPMB/UDDCD88" ,
  "S1090"."/B28/S_UDDDY4S" AS "/CPMB/UDDDY4S" ,
  "S1091"."/B28/S_UDDCQ0M" AS "/CPMB/UDDCQ0M" ,
  "S1092"."/B28/S_UDDHZNC" AS"/CPMB/UDDHZNC" , 
  SUM ("F"."/B28/S_SDATA") AS "/CPMB/SDATA"
FROM "/B28/EUDIQSBV" "F"
JOIN "/B28/DUDIQSBVP" "DP" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBVP" = "DP"."DIMID"
JOIN "/BI0/0600000051" "Z10" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBV4" = "Z10"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDDZMED" "S1080" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBV1" = "S1080"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDD8DGN" "S1081" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBV2" = "S1081"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDDFNH0" "S1082" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBV3" = "S1082"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDDX6I4" "S1083" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBV4" = "S1083"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDDXGOI" "S1084" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBV5" = "S1084"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDD741B" "S1085" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBV6" = "S1085"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDDC4PW" "S1086" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBV7" = "S1086"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDD8UPI" "S1087" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBV8" = "S1087"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDD94IW" "S1088" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBV9" = "S1088"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDDCD88" "S1089" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBVA" = "S1089"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDDDY4S" "S1090" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBVB" = "S1090"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDDCQ0M" "S1091" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBVC" = "S1091"."SID"
JOIN "/B28/DUDIQSBVD" "DD" ON "F"."KEY_UDIQSBVD" = "DD"."DIMID"
JOIN "/B28/SUDDHZNC" "S1092" ON "DD"."/B28/S_UDDHZNC" = "S1092"."SID"
WHERE (((("F"."KEY_UDIQSBV6" = 28))
        AND (("F"."KEY_UDIQSBV2" = 40))
        AND (("F"."KEY_UDIQSBV8" = 2))
        AND (("F"."KEY_UDIQSBV9" IN (2 , 3 , 5 , 7, 8 , 10 , 11 , 
            13 , 14 , 15 , 16 , 18 , 19 , 20 , 21)))
        AND (("F"."KEY_UDIQSBV7" IN (2 ,3 ,4 ,5,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11, 
            12 ,13 ,15 ,17 , 18 , 19 , 20)))
        AND (("F"."KEY_UDIQSBVA" = 153))
        AND (("F"."KEY_UDIQSBVC" IN (7 ,9 , 17 , 18 ,19 ,20,26 ,
            27 ,28 , 29 ,30 , 31 , 33 ,35 ,37 ,39 ,40 ,41 ,43 ,44 ,46)))
        AND (("F"."KEY_UDIQSBVB" IN (15 , 17 ,18 ,19 ,22 ,23 ,24 ,
            25 ,26 ,28 ,30 ,31 ,32 ,33 ,34 ,35 ,36 ,37 ,38 ,39 ,40 ,
            42 ,43 ,44 ,45 ,46 ,47 ,48 ,51 ,54 ,55 ,59 ,60 ,63 ,64 ,
            65 ,66 ,67 ,68 ,69 ,70 ,72 ,73 ,74 ,75)))
        AND (("F"."KEY_UDIQSBV3" IN (3 ,5 ,13 ,16 ,21 ,25 ,26 ,31 ,
            32 ,33,39 ,40 ,41 ,42 ,43 ,44 ,48 ,53 ,54 ,55 ,56 ,57 ,
            59 ,60 ,63 ,67 ,72 ,73 ,76 ,79)))
        AND (("DD"."/B28/S_UDDHZNC" = 360))
        AND (("F"."KEY_UDIQSBV5" IN (2 ,3 ,4 ,7 ,8)))
        AND (("F"."KEY_UDIQSBV1" IN (59 ,190)))
        AND (("DP"."SID_0CHNGID" = 0))
        AND (("DP"."SID_0RECORDTP" = 0))
        AND (("DP"."SID_0REQUID" <= 122208))))
  AND "Z10"."SID" <> 2000008999
GROUP BY
  "S1080"."/B28/S_UDDZMED", 
  "S1081"."/B28/S_UDD8DGN",
  "S1082"."/B28/S_UDDFNH0",
  "S1083"."/B28/S_UDDX6I4",
  "S1084"."/B28/S_UDDXGOI",
  "S1085"."/B28/S_UDD741B",
  "S1086"."/B28/S_UDDC4PW",
  "S1087"."/B28/S_UDD8UPI",
  "S1088"."/B28/S_UDD94IW",
  "S1089"."/B28/S_UDDCD88",
  "S1090"."/B28/S_UDDDY4S",
  "S1091"."/B28/S_UDDCQ0M",
  "S1092"."/B28/S_UDDHZNC"
```

**And here is the explain plan:**

```
 SELECT STATEMENT ( Estimated Costs = 117,703 , Estimated #Rows = 2,613,944 )
  |
  ---   91 TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION
      |
      |--   6 LOAD AS SELECT SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6DF0_8B5A52DE
      |   |
      |   ---   5 NESTED LOOPS
      |       |   ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
      |       |   Estim. CPU-Costs = 23,804 Estim. IO-Costs = 2
      |       |
      |       |--   2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID /B28/SUDDHZNC
      |       |   |   ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
      |       |   |   Estim. CPU-Costs = 15,463 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
      |       |   |
      |       |   ------1 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN /B28/SUDDHZNC~001
      |       |           ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
      |       |           Search Columns: 1
      |       |           Estim. CPU-Costs = 8,171 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
      |       |           Access Predicates
      |       |
      |       ---   4 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID /B28/DUDIQSBVD
      |           |   ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
      |           |   Estim. CPU-Costs = 8,341 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
      |           |
      |           ------3 INDEX RANGE SCAN /B28/DUDIQSBVD~010
      |                   Search Columns: 1
      |                   Estim. CPU-Costs = 1,050 Estim. IO-Costs = 0
      |                   Access Predicates
      |
      ---   90 HASH GROUP BY
          |    ( Estim. Costs = 117,701 , Estim. #Rows = 2,613,944 )
          |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 9,692,785,028 Estim. IO-Costs = 117,393
          |
          ---   89 HASH JOIN
              |    ( Estim. Costs = 1,018 , Estim. #Rows = 2,613,944 )
              |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 4,919,768,467 Estim. IO-Costs = 862
              |    Access Predicates
              |
              |--   11 VIEW index$_join$_026
              |   |    ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 71 )
              |   |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 15,820,708 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
              |   |    Filter Predicates
              |   |
              |   ---   10 HASH JOIN
              |       |    Access Predicates
              |       |
              |       |--   8 INLIST ITERATOR
              |       |   |
              |       |   ------7 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN /B28/SUDDDY4S~001
              |       |           Search Columns: 1
              |       |           Estim. CPU-Costs = 478,575 Estim. IO-Costs = 0
              |       |           Access Predicates
              |       |
              |       ------9 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN /B28/SUDDDY4S~0
              |               ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 71 )
              |               Estim. CPU-Costs = 26,652 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
              |
              ---   88 HASH JOIN
                  |    ( Estim. Costs = 1,008 , Estim. #Rows = 2,613,944 )
                  |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 4,626,808,323 Estim. IO-Costs = 861
                  |    Access Predicates
                  |
                  |--   16 VIEW index$_join$_006
                  |   |    ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 257 )
                  |   |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 15,859,258 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
                  |   |    Filter Predicates
                  |   |
                  |   ---   15 HASH JOIN
                  |       |    Access Predicates
                  |       |
                  |       |--   13 INLIST ITERATOR
                  |       |   |
                  |       |   ------12 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN /B28/SUDDZMED~001
                  |       |            Search Columns: 1
                  |       |            Estim. CPU-Costs = 71,490 Estim. IO-Costs = 0
                  |       |            Access Predicates
                  |       |
                  |       ------14 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN /B28/SUDDZMED~0
                  |                ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 257 )
                  |                Estim. CPU-Costs = 73,152 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
                  |
                  ---   87 HASH JOIN
                      |    ( Estim. Costs = 998 , Estim. #Rows = 2,613,944 )
                      |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 4,333,781,729 Estim. IO-Costs = 860
                      |    Access Predicates
                      |
                      |-----17 TABLE ACCESS FULL /B28/SUDDX6I4
                      |        ( Estim. Costs = 7 , Estim. #Rows = 7,126 )
                      |        Estim. CPU-Costs = 1,460,670 Estim. IO-Costs = 7
                      |        Filter Predicates
                      ---   86 HASH JOIN
                          |    ( Estim. Costs = 982 , Estim. #Rows = 2,613,944 )
                          |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 4,054,123,372 Estim. IO-Costs = 853
                          |    Access Predicates
                          |
                          |--   22 VIEW index$_join$_010
                          |   |    ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 82 )
                          |   |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 15,809,908 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
                          |   |    Filter Predicates
                          |   |
                          |   ---   21 HASH JOIN
                          |       |    Access Predicates
                          |       |
                          |       |--   19 INLIST ITERATOR
                          |       |   |
                          |       |   ------18 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN /B28/SUDDFNH0~001
                          |       |            Search Columns: 1
                          |       |            Estim. CPU-Costs = 363,600 Estim. IO-Costs = 0
                          |       |            Access Predicates
                          |       |
                          |       ------20 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN /B28/SUDDFNH0~0
                          |                ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 82 )
                          |                Estim. CPU-Costs = 29,402 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
                          |
                          ---   85 HASH JOIN
                              |    ( Estim. Costs = 972 , Estim. #Rows = 2,613,944 )
                              |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 3,761,172,378 Estim. IO-Costs = 852
                              |    Access Predicates
                              |
                              |-----23 TABLE ACCESS FULL /BI0/0600000051
                              |        ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 3,013 )
                              |        Estim. CPU-Costs = 638,207 Estim. IO-Costs = 2
                              |        Filter Predicates
                              ---   84 HASH JOIN
                                  |    ( Estim. Costs = 961 , Estim. #Rows = 2,614,378 )
                                  |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 3,482,910,035 Estim. IO-Costs = 850
                                  |    Access Predicates
                                  |
                                  |--   28 VIEW index$_join$_028
                                  |   |    ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 46 )
                                  |   |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 15,784,258 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
                                  |   |    Filter Predicates
                                  |   |
                                  |   ---   27 HASH JOIN
                                  |       |    Access Predicates
                                  |       |
                                  |       |--   25 INLIST ITERATOR
                                  |       |   |
                                  |       |   ------24 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN /B28/SUDDCQ0M~001
                                  |       |            Search Columns: 1
                                  |       |            Estim. CPU-Costs = 152,460 Estim. IO-Costs = 0
                                  |       |            Access Predicates
                                  |       |
                                  |       ------26 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN /B28/SUDDCQ0M~0
                                  |                ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 46 )
                                  |                Estim. CPU-Costs = 20,402 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
                                  |
                                  ---   83 HASH JOIN
 |    ( Estim. Costs = 950 , Estim. #Rows = 2,614,378 )
 |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 3,189,946,691 Estim. IO-Costs = 849
 |    Access Predicates
 |
 |--   33 VIEW index$_join$_018
 |   |    ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 21 )
 |   |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 15,768,808 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
 |   |    Filter Predicates
 |   |
 |   ---   32 HASH JOIN
 |       |    Access Predicates
 |       |
 |       |--   30 INLIST ITERATOR
 |       |   |
 |       |   ------29 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN /B28/SUDDC4PW~001
 |       |            Search Columns: 1
 |       |            Estim. CPU-Costs = 66,045 Estim. IO-Costs = 0
 |       |            Access Predicates
 |       |
 |       ------31 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN /B28/SUDDC4PW~0
 |                ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 21 )
 |                Estim. CPU-Costs = 14,152 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
 |
 ---   82 HASH JOIN
     |    ( Estim. Costs = 940 , Estim. #Rows = 2,614,378 )
     |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 2,897,002,547 Estim. IO-Costs = 848
     |    Access Predicates
     |
     |--   38 VIEW index$_join$_022
     |   |    ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 20 )
     |   |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 15,766,258 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
     |   |    Filter Predicates
     |   |
     |   ---   37 HASH JOIN
     |       |    Access Predicates
     |       |
     |       |--   35 INLIST ITERATOR
     |       |   |
     |       |   ------34 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN /B28/SUDD94IW~001
     |       |            Search Columns: 1
     |       |            Estim. CPU-Costs = 56,250 Estim. IO-Costs = 0
     |       |            Access Predicates
     |       |
     |       ------36 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN /B28/SUDD94IW~0
     |                ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 20 )
     |                Estim. CPU-Costs = 13,902 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
     |
     ---   81 HASH JOIN
         |    ( Estim. Costs = 930 , Estim. #Rows = 2,614,378 )
         |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 2,604,061,103 Estim. IO-Costs = 847
         |    Access Predicates
         |
         |--   43 VIEW index$_join$_014
         |   |    ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 8 )
         |   |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 15,750,358 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
         |   |    Filter Predicates
         |   |
         |   ---   42 HASH JOIN
         |       |    Access Predicates
         |       |
         |       |--   40 INLIST ITERATOR
         |       |   |
         |       |   ------39 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN /B28/SUDDXGOI~001
         |       |            Search Columns: 1
         |       |            Estim. CPU-Costs = 10,650 Estim. IO-Costs = 0
         |       |            Access Predicates
         |       |
         |       ------41 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN /B28/SUDDXGOI~0
         |                ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 8 )
         |                Estim. CPU-Costs = 10,902 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
         |
         ---   80 HASH JOIN
             |    ( Estim. Costs = 919 , Estim. #Rows = 2,614,378 )
             |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 2,311,137,359 Estim. IO-Costs = 846
             |    Access Predicates
             |
             |-----44 TABLE ACCESS FULL SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6DF0_8B5A52DE
             |        ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
             |        Estim. CPU-Costs = 7,291 Estim. IO-Costs = 2
             ---   79 HASH JOIN
                 |    ( Estim. Costs = 909 , Estim. #Rows = 2,614,378 )
                 |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 2,033,957,731 Estim. IO-Costs = 844
                 |    Access Predicates
                 |
                 |--   57 NESTED LOOPS
                 |   |    ( Estim. Costs = 6 , Estim. #Rows = 5 )
                 |   |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 71,420 Estim. IO-Costs = 6
                 |   |
                 |   |--   55 NESTED LOOPS
                 |   |   |    ( Estim. Costs = 4 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
                 |   |   |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 33,366 Estim. IO-Costs = 4
                 |   |   |
                 |   |   |--   52 NESTED LOOPS
                 |   |   |   |    ( Estim. Costs = 3 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
                 |   |   |   |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 25,024 Estim. IO-Costs = 3
                 |   |   |   |
                 |   |   |   |--   49 NESTED LOOPS
                 |   |   |   |   |    ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
                 |   |   |   |   |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 16,683 Estim. IO-Costs = 2
                 |   |   |   |   |
                 |   |   |   |   |--   46 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID /B28/SUDDCD88
                 |   |   |   |   |   |    ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
                 |   |   |   |   |   |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 8,341 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
                 |   |   |   |   |   |
                 |   |   |   |   |   ------45 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN /B28/SUDDCD88~001
                 |   |   |   |   |            Search Columns: 1
                 |   |   |   |   |            Estim. CPU-Costs = 1,050 Estim. IO-Costs = 0
                 |   |   |   |   |            Access Predicates
                 |   |   |   |   |
                 |   |   |   |   ---   48 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID /B28/SUDD8UPI
                 |   |   |   |       |    ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
                 |   |   |   |       |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 8,341 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
                 |   |   |   |       |
                 |   |   |   |       ------47 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN /B28/SUDD8UPI~001
                 |   |   |   |                Search Columns: 1
                 |   |   |   |                Estim. CPU-Costs = 1,050 Estim. IO-Costs = 0
                 |   |   |   |                Access Predicates
                 |   |   |   |
                 |   |   |   ---   51 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID /B28/SUDD741B
                 |   |   |       |    ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
                 |   |   |       |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 8,341 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
                 |   |   |       |
                 |   |   |       ------50 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN /B28/SUDD741B~001
                 |   |   |                Search Columns: 1
                 |   |   |                Estim. CPU-Costs = 1,050 Estim. IO-Costs = 0
                 |   |   |                Access Predicates
                 |   |   |
                 |   |   ---   54 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID /B28/SUDD8DGN
                 |   |       |    ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
                 |   |       |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 8,341 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
                 |   |       |
                 |   |       ------53 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN /B28/SUDD8DGN~001
                 |   |                Search Columns: 1
                 |   |                Estim. CPU-Costs = 1,050 Estim. IO-Costs = 0
                 |   |                Access Predicates
                 |   |
                 |   ------56 TABLE ACCESS FULL /B28/DUDIQSBVP
                 |            ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 5 )
                 |            Estim. CPU-Costs = 38,054 Estim. IO-Costs = 2
                 |            Filter Predicates
                 |
                 ---   78 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID /B28/EUDIQSBV
                     |    ( Estim. Costs = 893 , Estim. #Rows = 3,032,059 )
                     |    Estim. CPU-Costs = 1,714,945,175 Estim. IO-Costs = 838
                     |    Filter Predicates
                     |
                     ---   77 BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS
                         |
                         ---   76 BITMAP AND
                             |
                             |--   60 BITMAP OR
                             |   |
                             |   |-----58 BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE /B28/EUDIQSBV~040
                             |   |        Search Columns: 1
                             |   |        Access Predicates
                             |   ------59 BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE /B28/EUDIQSBV~040
                             |            Search Columns: 1
                             |            Access Predicates
                             |
                             |--   64 BITMAP MERGE
                             |   |
                             |   ---   63 BITMAP KEY ITERATION
                             |       |
                             |       |-----61 TABLE ACCESS FULL SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6DF0_8B5A52DE
                             |       |        ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
                             |       |        Estim. CPU-Costs = 7,271 Estim. IO-Costs = 2
                             |       ------62 BITMAP INDEX RANGE SCAN /B28/EUDIQSBV~160
                             |                Search Columns: 1
                             |                Access Predicates
                             |
                             |-----65 BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE /B28/EUDIQSBV~050
                             |        Search Columns: 1
                             |        Access Predicates
                             |--   71 BITMAP OR
                             |   |
                             |   |-----66 BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE /B28/EUDIQSBV~080
                             |   |        Search Columns: 1
                             |   |        Access Predicates
                             |   |-----67 BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE /B28/EUDIQSBV~080
                             |   |        Search Columns: 1
                             |   |        Access Predicates
                             |   |-----68 BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE /B28/EUDIQSBV~080
                             |   |        Search Columns: 1
                             |   |        Access Predicates
                             |   |-----69 BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE /B28/EUDIQSBV~080
                             |   |        Search Columns: 1
                             |   |        Access Predicates
                             |   ------70 BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE /B28/EUDIQSBV~080
                             |            Search Columns: 1
                             |            Access Predicates
                             |
                             ---   75 BITMAP MERGE
                                 |
                                 ---   74 BITMAP KEY ITERATION
|
|-----72 TABLE ACCESS FULL /BI0/0600000051
|        ( Estim. Costs = 2 , Estim. #Rows = 3,013 )
|        Estim. CPU-Costs = 638,207 Estim. IO-Costs = 2
|        Filter Predicates
------73 BITMAP INDEX RANGE SCAN /B28/EUDIQSBV~070
         Search Columns: 1
         Access Predicates Filter Predicates
```

Comment: Do you have any star indexes?

Comment: 14 indexes exist on the main fact table, one for each of the 13 dimension columns, and one non-unique primary key index comprising of all 13 dimensions.

Comment: A non-unique primary key?

Comment: Could you list the indexes you have on the table `"/B28/EUDIQSBV"`? If possible the index definitions. There might be one index missing (not sure).

Comment: Your table names are "/B28/SUDD94IW" etc? Twenty years of Oracle experience -- never seen anything as horrible and just wrong as that.

Comment: @David, these are auto-generated tables from an application. Nomenclature is relevant to the application's internal workings.

Comment: @ThomasMueller I have added the list of indexes.

Comment: @NGAlgo yes, that's often the case. Can you name the app so I can avoid accidentally ever working with it for the rest of my life? :)

Comment: @David, Lol, that might be a little tough as these guys are pervasive. This is an SAP related application.

Comment: @NGAlgo Oh that's OK, they're already on my list.

Comment: From what I have been reading, the only thing I can see is suggestions to check for whether Oracle is using Bitmap indexes and doing the join on the largest table last using those bitmap indexes. Reading the explain plan, it looks like it is doing that. Does that mean this is about as fast as it can get?? Doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: It looks like the query is filtering by surrogate keys?  Which is weird, but may be helpful.  With all of those AND conditions, I'm assuming the final result is a small number of rows.  That means you want to use index access paths as much as possible.  Most of your indexes are btrees, if you convert them all to bitmap they should work together much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of the DBAs came up with something that is definitely helping the query run much faster. He has introduced a composite bitmax index on the main fact table. The index definition is as follows:

```
CREATE BITMAP INDEX "SAPSR3"."/B28/EUDIQSBV~TEST" 
ON "SAPSR3"."/B28/EUDIQSBV" 
("KEY_UDIQSBV6",
 "KEY_UDIQSBV2",
 "KEY_UDIQSBV8",
 "KEY_UDIQSBV9",
 "KEY_UDIQSBV7",
 "KEY_UDIQSBVA",
 "KEY_UDIQSBVC",
 "KEY_UDIQSBVB",
 "KEY_UDIQSBV3") 
TABLESPACE "PSAPSR3";
```

This has sped up the query from 7+ minutes to 1.5 minutes.